# How to calculate cross-validation with multiple scores for multiclass?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, precision-recall

I'm starting my first machine learning code with python. But, I encountered an error while computing the recall, precision and f1 for my multiclass model.

```py
X = pd.read_excel(path, dtype=int)
allarray = X.values
X_data = allarray[:,0:-1]
Y = allarray[:,-1]
X_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_data)

create_model = create_custom_model(n_features, n_classes, 8, 3)

estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=100, verbose=0)
scores = cross_validate(estimator, X_scaled, Y, cv=10, scoring=('precision', 'recall', 'f1'), return_train_score=False)
print(scores['precision'])
print(scores['recall'])
print(scores['f1'])
```

I'm getting this error:

```py
ValueError: Target is multiclass but average='binary'. Please choose another average setting.
```

But `cross_validate` has no parameter `average`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the default `average` setting for precision, recall, and F1 scores applies to binary classification only.

What you should do is replace the `scoring=('precision', 'recall', 'f1')` argument in your `cross_validate` with something like

```
scoring=('precision_macro', 'recall_macro', 'f1_macro')
```

There are several suffix options available for each metric - `macro`, `micro`, `weighted` etc. See the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter), the example, and the score links therein.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not with `cross_validate`, this occurs because of scoring(in precision method you have average parameter). You can set the parameter in scoring methods